# nopcommerce 3.40 Deployment cant create database

Tags: visual-studio, nopcommerce

I installed on localhost with a local database.  I compiled in Release mode - Any CPU.  I have recopied the file system set from publish to the root folder as always.

I am taken directly to the install page.  I try to install using my websites database server name. Ive tried reconnecting to an existing database.

I get the error message (Ive tried both connection methods):

```
Setup failed: Sequence contains more than one element
```

So i tried to just create a new database.  i get error:

```
Setup failed: An error occurred while creating the database: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

I have checked to make sure my username and password are correct for the database. I think maybe i need to reset the install files some how? I have tried everything from delete to editing the settings.txt file in the App_data folder. still cant get passed the install

Comment: how did you fix this? Locally did the setup without any problem. Now, using Azure, always get prompt with the following error: Setup failed: Database does not exist or you don't have permissions to connect to it

Answer (score 1):

You don't have permission to create a new database using these credentials. You should configure SQL Server to allow it

Comment: yea, maybe, I have just opened up a ticket with my hosting provider to check on my database credentials. Thanks. ill let you know

Answer (score 0):

Most shared hosting doesn't allow you to create database from code. To overcome this, do:

1. Manually create database on your host
2. Get the connection string / connection info
3. Enter the info in [2] during installation, make sure you uncheck "create database if it doesn't exist"

Comment: I have tried this except not with the connection string.  I used the server name and database name.  No luck though

Answer (score 0):

The nopCommerce install never creates a database.  If you so choose... nopCommerce will create tables.

Edit: I am marking this the answer because this concept helped solve both new database creation and connecting to existing databases.